# Changing color from all the links

Tags: javascript

I want to change the color from all the links in my `<ul class="menu">`, but it's not changing colors for me. I am a complete beginner with javascript and I am doing some exercises.

My  `<ul class="menu">`:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="">hello</a></li>
<li><a href="">hello</a></li>
<li><a href="">hello</a></li>
<li><a href="">hello</a></li>
```

What am I doing wrong in my javascript?

```
        var x=document.getElementByClass("menu");
        if(x){
            var e =x.getElementsByTagName("a");
            for(var i=0; i<e.length; i++){
                e[i].style.color='yellow';
            }
        }
```

Comment: There's no function `getElementByClass`. It's `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: the text is outside of the links, so what color are you changing?

Comment: @Barmar still not working.

Comment: @malkassem Sorry typo in this code. Got it in the <a> and its still not working

Comment: Why are you doing this with JS instead of changing the CSS?

Comment: @Barmar Just an exercise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you need to call is `getElementsByClassName`. And it returns a `NodeList`, so you have to iterate over the results.

```
var menus = document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
for (var j = 0; j < menus.length; j++) {
    var e = menus[j].getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0; i<e.length; i++){
        e[i].style.color='yellow';
    }
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZV6b/)

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks didn't knew that.

Comment: Since there can (and usually are) multiple elements with the same class name, how else could it work?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought that it didn't work because of the multiple elements. Didn't knew what to do though and wasn't sure that was the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you look at some of the developer tools (e.g. firebug) that are available for whatever browser you are using.  Many of them have a console that allows you to run javascript on the current page you are viewing.

If you had tried to run your code in firebug console (it's just the one I'm most familiar with), it would have given you an error telling you that getElementByClass is not a function.

If nothing else, doing so can help give you an idea of at least where a chunk of javascript is error-ing.

But yeah, your problem is that you are looking for the function getElementsByClassName instead of getElementsByClass.

Also, I'm assuming you want the "hello"s inside of your anchor tags:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
<li><a href="">hello</a></li>
<li><a href="">hello</a></li>
<li><a href="">hello</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is: `getElementsByClassName()`

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("menu");
```

Comment: This function is only supported in modern browsers. If you are running an older browser this function will not work.

Comment: BTW is `Elements` not `Element`.. `getElementsByClassName`